# Get Value Data Hidden On C3js

Tags: c3.js

I'am using chart plugins from c3js.org like this:

```
data: {
    x : 'x',
    columns: [['data1',10,20,30],['data2',40,28,10]]
    type: 'bar',
    hide: ["hide1","hide2"],
    onclick: function(d,i){
                console.log(d);
    },
    labels: true
},
```

Is there a way to get value from data hidden above?

Thanks before, and sorry for bad my english.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? The ["hide1", "hide2"] should probably be ["data1", "data2"] if you want to hide those data columns.

Comment: The ["hide1","hide2"] like this ["a","b"] not data1 or data2. It's imposible to get value a or b.

Comment: Syafrizal, I just saw a solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700379/hide-some-graphic-elements-c3js-without-unloading-data/27701278#27701278 - that may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to hide the data, or get the value of the hide array from the click event? If the latter, in the onclick event, you can use:

```
this.data.shown()
```

to get the array of shown data objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an array of the hidden values, you can do a difference of all the values and the shown values. Using lodash's difference (or you can write your own), it looks something like this:

```
var allVals = chart.data();
var shownVals = chart.data.shown();
var diff = _.differenceBy(allVals, shownVals, 'id');
```